# Incorrect MathJax rendering in suggested edits

Tags: bug, editing, mathjax, review-queue

The [edit suggestion](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/397) I've made renders completely fine on the actual page:

> [image: normal]

However, in the edit suggestion both versions of the post are broken:

> [image: broken]

Comment: This is a very old and persistant bug with an easy fix (just show a view that _isn't_ side by side) that the staff doesn't care to fix. Let's hope they care now. So, in other words, this is a SE-wide issue.

Comment: Anyway, the cause is that the side-by-side highlighter breaks the mathjax environment such that something like `$\LaTeX` is being rendered instead of `$\LaTeX$`.

Comment: Also duplicated here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits **or** https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/having-mathjax-rendering-issue-in-suggested-edits-screen and is **answered** here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232123/mathjax-half-broken-in-suggested-edit-diffs --- meta.SE is the place for system-wide issues.

Answer (score 1):

As a mentioned in chat, a workaround for the reviewer is the following:

1. To see the original rendering, simply use the link to the current post.
2. To see the suggested rendering, use the 'improve edit'(or something like that) button to see it in the preview of your 'edit'